# Как извлечь субтитры из потокового видео?

Tags: видео

Нужно извлечь с сайта подключаемые субтитры к [видео](http://www.ntv.ru/peredacha/sledstvie/m2320/o356539/comments/). Видео файл с сайта не содержит субтитров, они лежат в отдельном файле. Так вот нужно его найти и скачать.
Просмотр кода и подгружаемых файлов страницы ничего не дал. Можно ли ещё каким-то образом загрузить файл субтитрами с сайта?

Comment: Зависит от того, как вшили сабы. Вполне вероятно вы можете решить этот вопрос с помощью ffpmpeg'a

Comment: Файл субтитров лежит отдельно, в файле с видео их нет. Задача в том, чтобы найти этот файл субтитров и загрузить отдельно.

Comment: В исходнике страницы найдите тег <subtitles>, в нем будет путь. Вот сабы для указанного вам видео: http://www.ntv.ru/home/vtt/2015/20151002/T172640.vtt

Comment: Большое спасибо, искал по  старинке .ass и .srt.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Spasibo za podskazku kak skachat' subtitri