# Как вытащить субтитры из плеера на сайте?

Tags: видео, плеер

Мне нужно вытащить субтитры из плеера на данном сайте https://findanime.net/serdce_mecha_shanhe__A5678/series2 . Сабы от FSG Libertas отдельно искала, но не нашла. Пробовала все способы, которые нашла в поисковике. Просмотрела исходный код страницы. Все похожие вопросы на этом сайте прошерстила. Если я и делаю что-то не так, то не понимаю, что именно. Мне нужна помощь. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У меня та же проблема, что и описывалась в одном из ранее задаваемых вопросов на этом сайте: "Нужно извлечь с сайта подключаемые субтитры к видео. Видео файл с сайта не содержит субтитров, они лежат в отдельном файле. Так вот нужно его найти и скачать. Просмотр кода и подгружаемых файлов страницы ничего не дал." - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456188/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE

Comment: https://anime-portal.ru/3974-mech-serdca-gor-i-rek.html - еще этот сайт, который более удобен, но с ним тоже мучаюсь. Дело не сдвигается с мертвой точки.